# if else php scipt that gets current month with full name

Tags: php

I am trying to solve a quiz question given on class today regarding the basic if else statements for php coding.

The question is as below:

> Write a script that gets the current month and prints one of the
>   following responses,  depending on whether it's August or not:
>
> > It's August, so it's really hot.
> >     Not August, so at least not in the peak of the heat.
>
> Hint given in the question: the function to get the current month is
>   '`date('F', time())`' for the month's full name.

Okay. So this is what I managed to write:

```
<?php
  $month=date("F");
  if ($month="F") {
    echo "It's August, so it's really hot.";
  }
  else {
    echo "Not August, so at least not in the peak of the heat.";
  }
?>
```

And I know for sure I'm doing it wrong at the date function. I am confused. I don't know how to use the hint `date('F', time())` from the question. Lend a helping hand, anyone?

Comment: You're performing an assignment here `if ($month="F")`. Use `==`. `if ($month=="August")`

Comment: And when will `$month == 'F'`?  Never.

Comment: `date('F')` is going to produce a full textual representation such as `January` or `August` as stated in the [DOCS](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) so after you've fixed your `if()` to use `==` instead of just `=` then you will have to change the `"F"` into the actual month you want to find.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be:

```
<?php
  $month = date('F', time());
  if ($month == 'August')
  {
    echo 'It\'s August, so it\'s really hot.';
  }
  else
  {
    echo 'Not August, so at least not in the peak of the heat.';
  }
?>
```

Because '`date('F', time())`' returns the full name of the month.

Comment: @Jurik And `if ($month=="August")` (`==` instead of `=`) ?

Comment: @Gwenc37 Why am I getting this Warning message when I test this code live: date() [function.date]: It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected 'America/New_York' for 'EDT/-4.0/DST' instead on line 1

Answer (score 2):

The result of `date("F");` is a word. Rather get the number to then solve if the number is 8.

```
   <?php
      $month = date("n"); // Get the number of the month, 1-12
      if ($month == 8) { // 8 is august
        echo "It's August, so it's really hot.";
      } else {
        echo "Not August, so at least not in the peak of the heat.";
      }
    ?>
```

or if you prefere working with strings

```
   <?php
      $month = date("F"); // Get name of the month
      if ($month == "August") { // If the given month is "august"
        echo "It's August, so it's really hot.";
      } else {
        echo "Not August, so at least not in the peak of the heat.";
      }
    ?>
```

Too summon up the answer:

First of all you need two equal signs in a if statement if you want to check if the variable is equal to something.

Secondly the `date("F")` returns a string of the current month, `"January - December"`. What your code says is if the variable $month is the string "F" then do something. But the variable $month returns a string of the month and that is currently April and will never be "F".

Comment: Or use `'F'` and check for `'August'`?

Comment: I feel more comfortable working with numbers instead of strings, but yes that is also possible

Comment: Also, August is 8 not 7.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
  $month=date('M');
  if ($month=="Aug") {
    echo "It's August, so it's really hot.";
  }
  else {
    echo "Not August, so at least not in the peak of the heat.";
  }
?>
```